# Calculation of leap years doesn't seem to match JavaScript Date

Tags: javascript, date

Trying to figure out a correlation between leap year calculations and the Date object in JavaScript (just because I want to know why).  I am NOT looking to use the Date() object to figure out leap years - that's not the point.

Executing this:

```
new Date(43 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toUTCString()
```

Produces this:

```
"Fri, 21 Dec 2012 00:00:00 GMT"
```

Which is off by 11 days (leap year related). So, I tried to do this mathematically:

```
1970 * 0.2425 = 477.72499999999997
2013 * 0.2425 = 488.1525
Difference: 10.427500000000009
```

Now, I also noticed that the difference in years is 43, and 43 * 0.2425 also equals 10.4275, which of course makes sense, but even rounding this off would only give 10.  Why is the JavaScript Date() object off by 11 days?

One more thing - I also tried this:

```
function test(y) {
    return new Date((y * 365 + Math.round((y+1) * 0.2425)) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toUTCString();
}
```

Which seems works well, until I get to the year 2000 (test(30)), in which case I get "Sun, 02 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT".  I'm guessing this is because of the 400 year rule - but I though that would be taken care of mathematically using ".2425".  I'm missing something, but not sure what.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Update: Just to add, I'm also looking for a math calculation (not any loops) that can tell me the number of milliseconds required to pass to the Date() object for a given year (without using the Date object itself!). Is it not possible to use math to calculate the leap years for a given year, and then the milliseconds required for Date()?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Date objects, or javascript in general, other than it's the medium you're using for calculation.

Comment: The date object is off by 11 days because there have been 11 leap years between now and 1970.

Comment: I know that there are 11 days - I wasn't clear however.  I wanted to know WHY my math was off.  The whole point of the 4-100-400 rule is because of the .2425 extra days per year, and theoretically, it should be possible to calculate the result of the 4-100-400 rules over a span of years using the fraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mathematical calculations are wrong, as you're starting on a year that isn't a leap year. For example, if you only had one year and you did that (and it wasn't a leap year), you'd get 0.2425 instead of 0, the correct answer. Using your method of working out, take this:

> 2010 * 0.2425 = 487.425
>   2011 * 0.2425 = 487.6675
>   Calculated difference: 0.2425
>   Correct days for leap years: 0

As both of them are not leap years, there should not be any extra days allocated. Another example:

> 2012 * 0.2425 = 487.91
>   2013 * 0.2425 = 488.1525
>   Calculated difference: 0.2425
>   Correct days for leap years: 1

To prove that JavaScript's date object *is* in fact correct, let's look at the leap years from 1970:

```
1972
1976
1980
1984
1988
1992
1996
2000
2004
2008
2012
```

... a total of 11 days. The implementation of the JavaScript `Date()` constructor actually checks for the following:

```
year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0 || year % 400 === 0
```

**EDIT:** You could use something like this - see if this is what suits your needs:

```
function test(y)
{   var floor = Math.floor;
    // y -= 1970; // if you want it to be full years instead of years since 1970
    var value = (365 * y + floor((y + 1) / 4) + floor((y + 369) / 400) - floor((y + 69) / 100)) * 86400000;
    return new Date(value).toUTCString();
}
```

This adds one day for every fourth year, then subtracts one day every 100 years, then adds back one (to cancel out the subtraction every 100 years) every 400 years.

Note that a day is *not* added at the start of a year, for example 1972 results in 0 days being added for leap years, as it is the start of the year and it has not reached the end of February yet.

Comment: The OP could add an offset of 0.5 to allow for the half day accumulated since 1968. But the calculation will fail in 2100 unless the centenary rule is allowed for.

Comment: @RobG: and also remove the 0.25 offset that was there (don't know why that's there).

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear in my post, but I'm mainly looking for a math calculation (not loop related) that can tell me the number of milliseconds required to pass to the Date() object for a given year. Is this possible WITHOUT having to create a date object? I have my reasons. ;)

Comment: You are close.  You forgot to subtract the epoch year 1970. ;)  Just put "y = y - 1970" after "var floor...".

Comment: Oh, I see, you were using my example, taking the difference in years as the argument, instead of the year itself; sorry. ;)

Comment: BTW: Why did you use "369" and "69"?

Comment: @James: because it's for the year 2100, not 2070.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see.  Because the function is accepting the DIFFERENCE of 1970 and a given date, it's adjusting accordingly, got it, thanks. :)